# Upgrade from .NET 4.5 MVC 4 to .NET 4.5.2 MVC 5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Almost the same [scenario as before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205654/upgrade-from-mvc-4-4-5-to-mvc-5-4-5-1) but this time I need to upgrade an app from .NET 4.5 (MVC 4) to 4.5.2 (MVC 5.2). I'd solved the previous issue by doing it on a Win 8 machine. It didn't work on Win 7.
Now, doing the same procedures (on a Win 8 machine) I have problems again.

I've [followed the steps](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2):

1. Upgraded all projects to Framework 4.5.2.
2. Checked for the Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers to uninstall it and it didn't exist.
3. Did the **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** step, and upgraded **Microsoft.ASPNET MVC** to 5.2 and **Microsoft.ASPNET Web API** to 2.2.
4. Edited all Web.Config files.
5. I've tried the Final Steps (Unload Project...) but the GUID was already gone.

The project builds fine but when I run it I get a Server Error page:

```
Attempt by security transparent method   
'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security 
critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed.
```

I've tried all solutions that I found on the Net but no luck.

Is there anything else I need to do it because of the target versions 4.5.2/5.2?

UPDATE 1

Removed WebMatrix.Data and WebMatric.WebData. Now I get 403.14 error. The request hits Global.asax Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute method but it doesn't go into Application_Start.

Comment: Are you actually using WebMatrix?  I've have had WebMatrix packages get added to my projects before without realizing it or intending for them to be there.

Comment: Yes, I have WeMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData and I don't use WebMatrix. I've removed them. Now, I get the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error. The request doesn't hit the Global.asax at all.

Comment: Have you seen this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden

Comment: Yes. I've tried to include the modules setup lines in the web.config. No luck. I run the app with the VS 2013 built in server and I'm not sure how to reset ASP.NET on it or check the app pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. I use Fluent Validation in the project and  didn't update FluentValidation.MVC4 to MVC5.